# Deploying distributed queue mechanism on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, queue, google-cloud-messaging, priority-queue, google-cloud-pubsub

### Background

I have a system working on Google Cloud. This system built on Micro-services architecture. The application communicating with each other with queues. Currently, I using Azure Storage Queues and want to move this managed service into GCP too.

### Requirements

Mandatory:

1. Max processing time - 1 second to 1 hour.
2. Ack mechanism to mark tasks as completed.
3. Scaleable solution - should support the load of a few thousands of messages per second.
4. Support `pull`ing of messages.

Nice to have:

1. Handle priorities - some tasks queues are more important than others.
2. Managed solution - I prefer to use a managed solution rather than install it my self.

### Solutions I have checked

I already checked those services and I refused it because:

- Microsoft Azure Storage Queue - Outside of google cloud.
- Google Cloud PubSub - Not meet the mandatory requirement - Processing time is limited to 10 minutes.
- Google Cloud Task - Seems like mostly designed for serverless applications, which are not suitable for my application.

I also check the RabbitMQ solution which seems to support all my requirements, except the one of 'managed solution'. It seems like GCP not provide RabitMQ as a service. So, I'll have to deploy it into virtual machines and make all the configuration my self...

### The question

To be honest, it seems like the solution that I'm looking for should be pretty common. Nothing really special. But, all of the services I described here have some critical cons.

Which service did I miss here?

Comment: Where did you found in the documentation that processing time is limited to 10 minutes for pubsub? I found some topics where it gave errors at 30 minutes but no 10 minutes limits, I'm curious

Comment: See this: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/608 Ack deadline is 600 seconds. Maybe you can extend this deadline. It's also thrown me exception while asking to the larger deadline on SDK (.net core).

Comment: Google Cloud Pub/Sub allows you to extend the deadline to longer than 600s; it's just that it has to be done in 600s increments. In other words, you can't call ModAckDeadline with a value greater than 600s, but you can call it close to the deadline for 600s to continue to extend it. If you are using the client libraries, this happens in the background automatically up to the MaxExtension, which should be able to be set to something more than 600s. If it can't be, then that's a bug in the .net implementation.

Comment: Have you been able to work out the distributed queue mechanism approach? Could you share your experience?

Comment: We are working with RabbitMQ instead. They don't have this issue.